# Chazal's organizational skills

Tags: talmud-gemara

Why didn't Chazal organize the Shas in a more organized fashion and put all sugyahs that are related into one place instead of having us have to go from Mesechta to Mesechta trying to work through a sugya?

Comment: The Rambam apparantly liked your suggestion. The Talmud itself however, has the goal of trying to teach you how to think, and to love thinking deeply, in addition to being a code of law. Therefore, orderly contents cannot always be the goal.

Comment: @DavidKenner, sounds like the makings of a good answer if you can provide evidence for it.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but I've been enjoying Rabbi Kessin's series of classes where he breaks down each Order of Mishna in 6 separate ideas, and shows how each tractate in the Order discusses that idea. In other words, why each tractate is in its specific Order. Here is the link to the first Shiur: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fvs8Huq5O-o

Answer (score 2):

Shas is organized, by definition,.
(shas = shisha (6) sidrai (orginized sets) mishna (of the mishna)).
  if you do not understand the organization it does not mean it is not organized

The Rambam explains the organization of the mishna in his introduction to it
Starting [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.15.1?lang=bi)

The gemoro comes after learning all the mishnah and then analyzing it one by one with everything else that you know.

They probably organized it in a way that was more simple to remember by heart,  (if you are referring to the Talmud (they kept the same order just they added a commentary, if they would change the order it would be harder for the people that learned the mishna) then any knowledge you learn to understand it fully you need to learn the whole thing, by learning the parts that are not connected to the sugya it helps you understand the sugya better, kol hatorah kula inyan echod hu, (even when learning the Rambam who is supper organized you still one need to look at other places in his work to fully understand one halocho (details of it are sometimes brought in other places))